Source for scalability challenge for number of finite element nodes per process
Context
In distributed simulation of a finite element mesh with $N$ nodes and $P$ processes, a professor stated to me that "achieving good scaling for more than 25,000 finite element nodes per process is very challenging and is a well-known problem in HPC". I asked to see if he had a particular source for this, since it seems like a very specific claim---and I imagine the claim is not always 25,000 since this would be contingent also on the particular hardware your executing a simulation on. He was, unfortunately, not able to provide a source. For reference, we are generally interested in simulating static PDEs like linear elasticity.
Question
Edit: Based on discussions in the comments and answers, there must have been a miscommunication between my advisor and me. The modified question should really be: "Where does the claim that it is challenging to achieve good scaling below 25,000 finite element nodes per process come from"?
Where does the claim that good scaling (strong or weak?) beyond 25,000 finite element nodes per process is a challenge come from? Is this a limitation of factorizers/iterative solvers?
Attempt
I have been able to find some papers describing the design of software and algorithms for large-scale finite element simulations, but only one of them (see ref [1]) mentions the 25,000 number explicitly, and the others do not seem to make a claim regarding this specific number. In ref [1], it does mention "down to 25,000 nodes per core" which implies to me that the challenge is more like adding more processes such that each process handles fewer nodes is the goal, which also makes sense since at some point communications would exceed computations during finite element assembly/solution for $P >> N$. Perhaps this number could be due to the fact that if you have 25,000 finite element nodes per process, and an equal number of degrees of freedom such that $\text{dim}(u_j) = 25000$ for a linear system $K_j u_j = f_j$ on process $j$, then one would end up with a sparse matrix $K_j \in \mathbb{R}^{25000 \times 25000}$ which might be challenging to factorize? But this is just postulation.
References
[1] : J. Hoffman, J. Jansson, and N. Jansson. FEniCS-HPC: Automated
Predictive High-Performance Finite Element Computing with Applications in
Aerodynamics. In Parallel Processing and Applied Mathematics, pages 356–365.
Springer International Publishing, 2016. doi: 10.1007/978-3-319-32149-3 34.
[2] :  W. Bangerth, C. Burstedde, T. Heister, and M. Kronbichler.
Algorithms and data structures for massively parallel generic adaptive finite element codes. ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, 38(2):1–28, December
2011. doi: 10.1145/2049673.2049678.
[3] : W. Bangerth, R. Hartmann, and G. Kanschat. deal.II—A general-purpose object-
oriented finite element library. ACM Trans. Math. Softw., 33(4), August 2007.
doi: 10.1145/1268776.1268779.

As you suspected, and as @Victor Eijkhout already said, the challenge is to go below a certain number of degrees of freedom per process because then there is just not enough work for each process to do to amortize the cost of communication.
Where that number is depends on the specific code, and the problem you're solving. 25,000 unknowns per process is probably as good a number as any other. I believe that in your reference 1, we put the limit at 100,000/process. In other ones of my papers, we've found 50,000/process as a reasonable place below which our codes stop to scale, and in yet others 40,000. If you want to see some examples, take a look here (Fig.s 7, 9, 10), here (Fig. 6), and here (Fig. 4). In all cases, the vertical line is at 100,000 unknowns per MPI process, but it's clear that one could also have chosen 50,000/process to make the same point -- a code does not magically become entirely inefficient at that point, but just starts to lose some scalability.
If you just look around the literature long enough, you'll find that that limit to scalability seems to lie somewhere between $10^4$ and $10^5$ for most codes that utilize implicit discretizations and iterative solvers.

That sort of numbers come from simulations in an MPI distributed memory context. Let's say you're doing some iterative solver and you alternate a simple grid update with some border exchange. The grid exchange is a few floating point operations per grid point, and running at 10^9 ops/second. The border exchange costs a few microseconds, so that's the equivalent of a few thousand operations. And there you have it: if you don't want your code to be dominated by communication overhead, you need to have enough grid points.
"achieving good scaling for more than 25,000 finite element nodes per process is very challenging" By my above analysis it's precisely the small case that's hard to scale, not the large case. Maybe that statement holds more true for direct system solvers, which have a much more complicated mix of small & large grain operations and synchronization.
"that the challenge is more like adding more processes such that each process handles fewer nodes" That's strong scaling, and most people accept that you can only do that up to a certain point. Good thing that most problems can be scaled up by increasing accuracy, so we worry more about weak scaling.

"achieving good scaling for more than 25,000 finite element nodes per process is very challenging" - this sounds totally the wrong way around to me, I would expect "less" rather than "more". It would be good to see evidence to support this surprising claim.

@IanBush I expressed the same in my second paragraph. I'd be curious what the [1] reference actually says. The Fenics people are no idiots.

Indeed. Were I betting man I would put money on it being the other way around, and suspect a mistake in communication here.

I think there must have been a miscommunication as well. It really wouldn't make sense for scaling challenges to be associated with a problem size (i.e., number of finite element nodes) that is larger (i.e., > 25,000).
